# Fill in missing dates pandas based off max and min

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, conditional-statements

How can I create a python statement for a conditional

I have a dataframe like the one below.  I was wondering how can i fill in missing dates based of the max min dates in a dataframe.

```
Day            Movie          Rating
2017-01-01     GreatGatsby    5
2017-01-02     TopGun         5
2017-01-03     Deadpool       1
2017-01-10     PlanetOfApes   2
```

How can I make something that filles in the missing dates to something like

```
Day            Movie          Rating
2017-01-01     GreatGatsby    5
2017-01-02     TopGun         5
2017-01-03     Deadpool       1
2017-01-04     0              0
2017-01-05     0              0
2017-01-06     0              0
2017-01-07     0              0
2017-01-08     0              0
2017-01-09     0              0
2017-01-10     PlanetOfApes   2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `resample` + `first`/`last`/`min`/`max`:

```
df.set_index('Day').resample('1D').first().fillna(0).reset_index()

         Day         Movie  Rating
0 2017-01-01   GreatGatsby     5.0
1 2017-01-02        TopGun     5.0
2 2017-01-03      Deadpool     1.0
3 2017-01-04             0     0.0
4 2017-01-05             0     0.0
5 2017-01-06             0     0.0
6 2017-01-07             0     0.0
7 2017-01-08             0     0.0
8 2017-01-09             0     0.0
9 2017-01-10  PlanetOfApes     2.0
```

If `Day` isn't a `datetime` column, use `pd.to_datetime` to convert it first:

```
df['Day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Day'])
```

---

Alternative by Wen `asfreq`:

```
df.set_index('Day').asfreq('D').fillna(0).reset_index()

         Day         Movie  Rating
0 2017-01-01   GreatGatsby     5.0
1 2017-01-02        TopGun     5.0
2 2017-01-03      Deadpool     1.0
3 2017-01-04             0     0.0
4 2017-01-05             0     0.0
5 2017-01-06             0     0.0
6 2017-01-07             0     0.0
7 2017-01-08             0     0.0
8 2017-01-09             0     0.0
9 2017-01-10  PlanetOfApes     2.0
```

Comment: Share one more after resample. `df.set_index('Day').resample('D').asfreq().fillna(0).reset_index()`

Comment: @Wen Looks great. Learned a new thing. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Sorry , I missed tapped...on my phone..`.df.set_index('Day').asfreq(freq='D').fillna(0).reset_index()`

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (df.set_index('Day')
       .reindex(pd.date_range(df['Day'].min(), df['Day'].max()), fill_value=0)
       .reset_index())

print (df)
       index         Movie  Rating
0 2017-01-01   GreatGatsby       5
1 2017-01-02        TopGun       5
2 2017-01-03      Deadpool       1
3 2017-01-04             0       0
4 2017-01-05             0       0
5 2017-01-06             0       0
6 2017-01-07             0       0
7 2017-01-08             0       0
8 2017-01-09             0       0
9 2017-01-10  PlanetOfApes       2
```